Small Sample size
I have collected primary data from 100 tech startups. However, there are 23k active tech startups. Given that, how will I justify the small sample size. I am collecting the data from an emerging economy where I don't have secondary database for obtaining the startup related information. Collecting primary data from the 100 startups also was a huge task.

A sample size of $100$ seems fairly large to me. Do you mean to ask how to justify omitting $22,900$ firms?

It all depends on what you want to do with these data, but in general practical issues, money and effort required for collecting larger samples are always a valid justification - unless you want to do something with the data that isn't any good at that sample size.

If those 100 were randomly selected, then it may be perfectly adequate to take a sample of 100. It depends on what you are trying to estimate. The size of the population doesn't really matter, unless it is very small (close to 100) in which case you will need the finite population correction.
You can justify 100 by doing power analysis. This may tell you 100 is fine, or it may tell you that you need more. Results will vary depending on a) Your test statistic b) The effect size that you want to be able to detect and c) Your acceptable level of risk of  type 1 and type 2 error (often chosen as 0.05 and 0.20, but that is pretty arbitrary).

Yes, 100 randomly selected startups. I will do the power analysis and verify the result.

@Anu if those startups were randomly selected from the 23k popular, do you mean that every startup of the 23k had equal probability to end up into the sample? (I am asking because random does not yet mean uniform/equal probability)

@Sextus Empiricus Yes, every startup out of 23k had an equal chance of being selected. I have collected data from across the nation.
